# Changes to the Hot Network Questions List

Tags: discussion

[Updating the Hot Network Questions List - now with a bit more network and a little less "hotness"!](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/325060/updating-the-hot-network-questions-list-now-with-a-bit-more-network-and-a-litt)

There are some very nice new features around the HNQ list. I’m not going to repeat the contents of the official post here, but I wanted y’all to be aware of it and to give us a space to discuss any ELL specific impacts.